# Hibernate One-To-Many

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

Have a problem with hibernate. I have Entity User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")

public class User {
@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
@GeneratedValue
private Long userId;

@Column
@NotBlank(message = "Fill login")
private String login;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="user")
private List<Order> orders;

public List<Order> getOrders() {
    return orders;
}
public void addOrders(Order order) {
    this.orders.add(order);
}
```

Also like u can see user have orders. So in ORDER table i have FK that point to USER_ID so here it is my entity Order

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name="order_id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private long orderId;   
    @Column 
    private long user_id;
    @Column
    private Date dateBegin;
    private Date dateEnd;

}
```

and here my Unit Test

```
public class HibernateTutorial extends BaseTest{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Test
    public void hibernateTutorial(){        
        System.out.print(sessionFactory);       

        List<User> users =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
        List<Order> orders = users.get(0).getOrders(); 

        System.out.print(orders);   
        Assert.assertNotNull(users);    

    }

}
```

I have Exception when i run it:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property  entity.Order.user in entity.User.orders
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:576)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:541)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1177)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:324)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1162)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 38 more
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of User in your Order class.

Here is an [example of One-to-many.](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)

So, you might add something like this to the Order class:

```
private User user;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
public User getUser() {
  return this.user;
}
```

Comment: Do u mean 
private User user;

Comment: Yep, edited my answer to include a code snippet.  It would take the place of @Column private long user_id; in the Order class.

Comment: Did this fix your exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
@Column 
private long user_id;
```

Needs to be replaced with a reference to

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;
```

and a many-to-one mapping.

Comment: Could not determine type for:entity.User, at table: order, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)]

Answer (score 0):

The mappedBy attribute indicates the field in the associated table that defined the relationship.  If you want to keep the mappedBy as-is, you'd need to add:

```
private User user;
```

To your order class.  Additionally, you'll want to add a @ManyToOne on this side of the relationship and define the semantics of the join column.  The bi-directionality isn't always a requirement, but in this case, it seems like your business need is to get the user for a know order, and it is the correct approach.

As a general rule, you should use full Object relationships between Hibernate entities, rather than have the entities refer to each other's id values.  Hibernate will properly manage the saves and updates for you, and the fetching of ids vs. full objects is easy enough to manage on your own.